# Default values from wxPython notebook

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm really sorry if this question sounds really simple but I couldn't figure out the solution yet...

I'm using wxPython in order to create a GUI. I've used wx.Notebook, and created some tabs, all default configuration are located in the last tab.

My question is, how can I get these default values from the last tab and use it?!? I tried "pub" (wx.lib.pubsub), but I only get these default values after an event (e.g. button click). Also there is/are any magic to get these values after user modification without a button click?

Thanks all,

Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure how the values are being input into your program. If they're being entered into textboxes, you can intercept keypress events and get the values from them without waiting for a button to be pressed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the UI, you can keep the default config in a variable. A dictionary would probably work. Then when you create the tabs, you can pass them a dictionary. Alternatively, you could just save the defaults to a config file and then use Python to read it and load it into the UI. Python can parse csv, json, xml and whatnot right out of the box after all.

Comment: Great tip I haven't tested yet but for sure it will work =] Thanks a lot